# Relational DB racing conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm working with Ruby On Rails (but it doesn't really matter) with a SQL backend, either MySQL or Postgres.
The web application will be multi-process, with a cluster of app-server processes running and working on the same DB.

I was wondering: is there any good and common strategy to handle racing conditions?

Since it's going to be a DB-intense application, I can easily see how two clients can try to modify the same data at the same time.

Let's simplify the situation:

- Two clients/users GET the same data, it doesn't matter if this happens at the same time.
- They are served with two web pages representing the same data.
- Later both of them try to write some incompatible modifications to the same record.

Is there a simple way to handle this kind of situation?

I was thinking of using id-tokens associated with each record. This tokens would be changed upon updates of the records, thus invalidating any subsequent update attempt based on stale data (old expired token).

Is there a better way? Maybe something already built in MySQL?
I'm also interested in coding patterns used in this cases.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Optimistic locking

The standard way to handle this in webapps is to use what's referred to as "optimistic locking".

Each record has a unique ID and an integer (or timestamp, but integer is better) optimistic lock field. This oplock filed is initialized to 0 on record creation.

When you get the record you get the oplock field with it.

When you set the record you set the oplock value to the oplock you retrieved with the `SELECT` plus one and you make the `UPDATE` conditional on the oplock value still being what it was when you last looked:

```
UPDATE thetable
SET field1 = ...,
    field2 = ...,
    oplock = 1
WHERE record_id = ...
  AND oplock = 0;
```

If you lost a race with another session this statement will still succeed but it will report zero rows affected. That allows you to tell the user their change collided with changes by another user or to merge their changes and re-send, depending on what makes sense in that part of the app.

Many frameworks provide tooling to help automate this, and most ORMs can do it out of the box. [Ruby on Rails supports optimistic locking](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Optimistic.html).

Be careful when combining optimistic locking with pessimistic locking (as described below) for traditional applications. It can work, you just need to add a trigger on all optimistically lockable tables that increments the oplock column on an `UPDATE` if the `UPDATE` statement didn't do so its self. I [wrote a PostgreSQL trigger for Hibernate oplock support](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Hibernate_oplocks) that should be readily adaptable to Rails. You only need this if you're going to update the DB from outside Rails, but in my view it's always a good idea to be safe.

### Pessimistic locking

The more traditional approach to this is to begin a transaction and do a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` when fetching a record you intend to modify. You then hold the transaction open and idle while the user ponders what they're going to do and issue the `UPDATE` on the already-locked record before `COMMIT`ting.

This doesn't work well and I don't recommend it. It requires an open, often idle transaction for each user. This can cause problems with MVCC row cleanup in PostgreSQL and can cause locking problems in applications. It's also very inefficient for large applications with high user counts.

### Insert races

Dealing with races on `INSERT` requires you to have a suitable application level unique key on the table, so inserts fail when they conflict.

Comment: Indeed, pessimistic locking really is not an option in a web application because of the stateless HTTP request/response cycle. Usually database connections are either closed at the end of each HTTP request or cleaned up and reassigned to new requests at random.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. Also, `ActiveRecord::Locking::Optimistic` is exactly the kind of builtin feature I was hoping to find. It basically is an implementation of the id-token I was writing about. (the other answer on `ActiveRecord::Transactions` was useful too, thanks)